# Get function components of function call inside a function

Tags: r, metaprogramming

Is it possible to retrieve the function components of a function call? That is, is it possible to use `as.list(match.call())` on another function call.

The background is, that I want to have a function that takes a function-call and returns the components of said function call.

```r
get_formals <- function(x) {
  # something here, which would behave as if x would be a function that returns
  # as.list(match.call())
}

get_formals(mean(1:10))
# expected to get:
# [[1]]
# mean
#
# $x
# 1:10
```

The expected result is to have `get_formals` return as `match.call()` was called within the supplied function call.

```r
mean2 <- function(...) {
  as.list(match.call())
}
mean2(x = 1:10)
# [[1]]
# mean2
# 
# $x
# 1:10
```

## Another Example

The motivation behind this question is to check if a `memoise`d function already contains the cached values. `memoise` has the function `has_cache()` but it needs to be called in a specific way `has_cache(foo)(vals)`, e.g.,

```r
library(memoise)

foo <- function(x) mean(x)
foo_cached <- memoise(foo)

foo_cached(1:10) # not yet cached
foo_cached(1:10) # cached

has_cache(foo_cached)(1:10) # TRUE
has_cache(foo_cached)(1:3) # FALSE
```

My goal is to log something if the function call is cached or not.

```r
cache_wrapper <- function(f_call) {
  is_cached <- has_cache()() # INSERT SOLUTION HERE
  # I need to deconstruct the function call to pass it to has_cache
  # basically
  # has_cache(substitute(expr)[[1L]])(substitute(expr)[[2L]]) 
  # but names etc do not get passed correctly

  if (is_cached) print("Using Cache") else print("New Evaluation of f_call")
  f_call
}

cache_wrapper(foo_cached(1:10))
#> [1] "Using Cache"     # From the log-functionality
#> 5.5                   # The result from the function-call
```

Comment: I’m assuming `get_formals = function (expr) substitute(expr)[[2L]]` would not be sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: How many layers of environment are you dealing with?  I'm not sure whether you want Konrad's method or  need something more squirrely.  Where is your "function call" coming from, e.g.  some `deparse` operation?  If you could post a demo of the way you're going to use this retrieval thingy that would be helpful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph's solution is almost there, but I loose the names of the arguments.

Comment: I am dealing with only one layer. I will add another example to the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it that also gets the default values from the function if you didn't supply all the arguments:

```
get_formals <- function(call)
{
  f_list <- as.list(match.call()$call)
  func_name <- f_list[[1]]
  p_list <- formals(eval(func_name))
  f_list <- f_list[-1]
  ss <- na.omit(match(names(p_list), names(f_list)))
  if(length(ss) > 0) {
    p_list[na.omit(match(names(f_list), names(p_list)))] <- f_list[ss]
    f_list <- f_list[-ss]
  }
  unnamed <- which(!nzchar(sapply(p_list, as.character)))
  if(length(unnamed) > 0)
  {
    i <- 1
    while(length(f_list) > 0)
    {
      p_list[[unnamed[i]]] <- f_list[[1]]
      f_list <- f_list[-1]
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
  c(func_name, p_list)
}
```

Which gives:

```r
get_formals(rnorm(1))
[[1]]
rnorm

$n
[1] 1

$mean
[1] 0

$sd
[1] 1
```

```
get_formals(ggplot2::ggplot())
[[1]]
ggplot2::ggplot

$data
NULL

$mapping
aes()

$...


$environment
parent.frame()
```

To get this to work one level in you could do something like:

```r
foo <- function(f_call) {
  eval(as.call(list(get_formals, call = match.call()$f_call)))
}

foo(mean(1:10))
[[1]]
mean

$x
1:10

$...
```

Comment: This brings me almost there. Do you know how to use this function one level in?
I.e., `foo <- function(f_call) return(get_formals(f_call))`?

Comment: Wonderful! That does it! I have implemented the `eval.parent` call of Konrad to your function. Will post an update to show the full solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `match.call()` to do argument matching.

```
get_formals <- function(expr) {
  call <- substitute(expr)
  call_matched <- match.call(eval(call[[1L]]), call)
  as.list(call_matched)
}

get_formals(mean(1:10))

# [[1]]
# mean
# 
# $x
# 1:10

library(ggplot2)
get_formals(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)))

# [[1]]
# ggplot
# 
# $data
# mtcars
# 
# $mapping
# aes(x = mpg, y = hp)

library(dplyr)
get_formals(iris %>% select(Species))

# [[1]]
# `%>%`
# 
# $lhs
# iris
# 
# $rhs
# select(Species)
```

---

***Edit:*** *Thanks for @KonradRudolph's suggestion!*

The function above finds the *right* function. It will search in the scope of the parent of `get_formals()`, not in that of the caller. The much safer way is:

```
get_formals <- function(expr) {
  call <- substitute(expr)
  call_matched <- match.call(eval.parent(bquote(match.fun(.(call[[1L]])))), call)
  as.list(call_matched)
}
```

The `match.fun()` is important to correctly resolve functions that are shadowed by a non-function object of the same name. For example, if `mean` is overwrited with a vector

```
mean <- 1:5
```

The first example of `get_formals()` will get an error, while the updated version works well.

Comment: Be careful that this finds the *right* function: it will search in the scope of the parent of `get_formals`, not in that of the caller. You can fix this by replacing `eval` with `eval.parent(bquote(match.fun(.(call[[1L]]))))` (that’s quite a handful, but the `match.fun` is important to correctly resolve functions that are shadowed by a non-function object of the same name).

Comment: @KonradRudolph thank you for your detailed advice. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is mostly based on [Allens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63399095/3048453), but implements Konrads comment regarding the `eval` and `eval.parent` functions.
Additionally, some `do.call` is thrown in to finalise the `cache_wrapper` from the example above:

```r
library(memoise)

foo <- function(x) mean(x)
foo_cached <- memoise(foo)

foo_cached(1:10) # not yet cached
#> [1] 5.5
foo_cached(1:10) # cached
#> [1] 5.5

has_cache(foo_cached)(1:10)
#> [1] TRUE
has_cache(foo_cached)(1:3)
#> [1] FALSE

# As answered by Allen with Konrads comment
get_formals <- function(call) {
  f_list <- as.list(match.call()$call)
  func_name <- f_list[[1]]
  # changed eval to eval.parent as suggested by Konrad...
  p_list <- formals(eval.parent(eval.parent(bquote(match.fun(.(func_name))))))
  f_list <- f_list[-1]
  ss <- na.omit(match(names(p_list), names(f_list)))
  if(length(ss) > 0) {
    p_list[na.omit(match(names(f_list), names(p_list)))] <- f_list[ss]
    f_list <- f_list[-ss]
  }
  unnamed <- which(!nzchar(sapply(p_list, as.character)))
  if(length(unnamed) > 0) {
    i <- 1
    while(length(f_list) > 0) {
      p_list[[unnamed[i]]] <- f_list[[1]]
      f_list <- f_list[-1]
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
  c(func_name, p_list)
}

# check if the function works with has_cache
fmls <- get_formals(foo_cached(x = 1:10))
do.call(has_cache(eval(parse(text = fmls[1]))),
        fmls[2])
#> [1] TRUE


# implement a small wrapper around has_cache that reports if its using cache
cache_wrapper <- function(f_call) {
  fmls <- eval(as.call(list(get_formals, call = match.call()$f_call)))
  is_cached <- do.call(has_cache(eval(parse(text = fmls[1]))),
                       fmls[2])
  if (is_cached) print("Using Cache") else print("New Evaluation of f_call")
  f_call
}

cache_wrapper(foo_cached(x = 1:10))
#> [1] "Using Cache"
#> [1] 5.5

cache_wrapper(foo_cached(x = 1:30))
#> [1] "New Evaluation of f_call"
#> [1] 5.5
```